# How to move a file with a variable to a folder with a variable name?

Tags: bash, variables, mv

I want to move file to a folder in a bash script, both having variables.

My code looks like:

```
name='test'
touch $name.file.txt
mkdir -p $name
mv $name.file.txt $name
```

This properly creates the directory only. The touch command does not create the file. If I create the file manually so that the mv command can function, the mv command also does not work. I've seen several similar questions but still can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I ran your script and it worked as expected. It created file, created directory and also moved the file into directory.

Comment: you ran it exactly as above? could it be some sort of version problem

Comment: I too ran your example and it works as expected. Can you try it again? What is the return code of `touch` (`echo $?`)? Does `touch` show an error?

Comment: It never gives errors. It just runs, but then doesn't run as expected for me

Answer (score 0):

I see 1 problem here, you can start the scrip from another path, so you need to use

```
cd /path/where-you_want_to_work
```

at the beginning of the scrip;
or just use full path names:

```
touch /path/path/$name.file.txt
```

Comment: i would like to path from current directory though. I want the script to work well on other people's computers

Comment: Your script is working, I have tested it, so may be there is a problem with owner of the working directory?
I mean you are starting the script from the user that is not owner of the directory?